# Test if stdin has input for C++ (windows and/or linux)

Tags: c++, testing, pipe, stdin

I basically want to test if stdin has input (like if you echo and pipe it). I have found solutions that work, but they are ugly, and I like my solutions to be clean.

On linux I use this:

```
bool StdinOpen() {
  FILE* handle = popen("test -p /dev/stdin", "r");
  return pclose(handle) == 0;
}
```

I know that I should add more error handling, but it's besides the point.

On windows I use this:

```
bool StdinOpen() {
  static HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  DWORD bytes_left;
  PeekNamedPipe(handle, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytes_left, NULL);
  return bytes_left;
}
```

That is fine for linux, but I want to know what are the equivalent APIs that I can call without using a pipe (like for `test -f $file` you do `fopen($file, "r") != NULL`). I have an inkling that I could `open("/dev/stdin", "r")` and do the same thing, but I want to know the best way to do it.

**Summary:** I want to know the APIs I could use to substitute for `test -p /dev/stdin` for linux, and, if you know a better solution for windows.

Comment: Your `PeekNamedPipe` solution fails if standard input is a file handle (rather than a pipe). Also, your `handle` variable should not be static. If the handle gets redirected while your app runs you're going to surprise yourself later.

Comment: @Billy: I don't think a handle could get randomly redirected. Sure, you might change what you consider to be stdin, but the old handle is still there. But I agree about the first part.

Comment: Lionel B provides some code for Linux at http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/841283-how-make-non-blocking-call-cin - the discussion's worth reading too.

Comment: I could test if stdin is a pipe using `DWORD dw; !GetConsoleMode(handle, &dw)` and use the current method, and otherwise use `_kbhit() != 0`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a solution for POSIX (Linux): I'm not sure what's the equivalent of poll() on Windows. On Unix, The file descriptor with number 0 is the standard input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>

int main(void)
{
        struct pollfd fds;
        int ret;
        fds.fd = 0; /* this is STDIN */
        fds.events = POLLIN;
        ret = poll(&fds, 1, 0);
        if(ret == 1)
                printf("Yep\n");
        else if(ret == 0)
                printf("No\n");
        else
                printf("Error\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Testing:

```
$ ./stdin
No
$ echo "foo" | ./stdin
Yep
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Now, I would be eternally grateful if you could tell me how to measure the input buffer size, but I don't want to sound like a question hog.

Comment: You can use read() to get the input. First set the file descriptor 0 to non-blocking using fcntl(), then read() will return the number of bytes read or 0 when there is no more incoming data.

Comment: +1. Another commonly-used alternative is `select()` - conceptually similar usage.  It's crucial to note that these ask the operating system if there's new data available from the descriptor - if you're operating at that level, you must use a `read()` directly on the descriptor too, you can't use library-level stdin streams or `std::cin` (unless you provide a new buffer implementation).

Comment: On my platform I can use fds.fd = fileno(stdin) instead of fds.fd = 0. This will improve platform independence if it is needed, not even sure though that there is a platform where stdin's fd is non-zero. I'm using an ARM Linux distro with a 3.2 kernel.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly at least more readable. POSIX defines stdin fileno to be 0 - see stdin(3p) - and there's also a define STDIN_FILENO with value 0 defined at stdio.h.

Comment: One should rather test the output `revent` after calling `poll(...)`, like `fds.events == fds.revents`

Answer (score 5):

Would this not work?

```
std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does NOT (at least on Windows). It always returns 0 unless you do a blocking call like peek() to invoke the console input APIs, which defeats the whole purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but does [`_kbhit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx) do what you need?

Comment: It only works for actual keyboard input in a console app. Not for redirected input!

Answer (score 1):

**[ POSIX ]** ioctl() is pretty straightforward and common since it's part of the **standard C POSIX library**, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html
Syntax: `ioctl(int fd, int opt, int *n)`
In this case `ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &available_bytes);`
**0** -> stdin
**FIONREAD** -> opt to ask for available bytes
**&available_bytes** -> pointer to the `int bytes` variable to store the available bytes.

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int stdin_avail() {
  int bytes = 0;
  if(ioctl(0,FIONREAD, &bytes) == -1){
    return -1;
  };
  return bytes;
}

int main(int argc, const char **args)
{
  int available_bytes = stdin_avail();
  printf("available: %i bytes\n", available_bytes);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had [LINUX] at the beginning of the answer + the guy was looking for new ways on both Windows and Linux. 
Also I didn't mean the standard C library, I corrected it. Let me know if I'm still wrong,

Comment: `FIONREAD` sets `int`, not `uint-64`. By using uint64 you likely read 8 bytes to much. If these are zero it *looks OK* ~ but you are actually reading uninitialised data. One should also always check if it returns success. For `FIONREAD` that is zero. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

```
return ::WaitForSingleObject(::GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), 3) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
```

Old question, but none of the (current) other answers work on Windows (and I might be looking it up again in an year :).